# Selenium - Getting nullpointer Exception while initiating Pagefatory.initelements at @BeforeTest where as working same code with @BeforeMedthod

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Getting nullpointer Exception while initiating Pagefatory.initelements at **@BeforeTest** where as working same code with **@BeforeMedthod**

```
public class HRMSAUT    
{    
    private WebDriver driver;    
    LoadUrl loadUrl;      
    Login loginUrl;  

    @BeforeClass    
    public void beforeClass()    
    {    
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
    }    

    @BeforeTest  //Initiating PageFatory Elements    
    public void beforeTest1()throws Exception     
    {    
        loadUrl=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoadUrl.class);    
        loginUrl=PageFactory.initElements(driver,Login.class);    
    }    

    @Test     
    public void HRMSlogin() throws Exception      
    {      
        loadUrl.load();      
        loginUrl.enterusername("Demo");      
        loginUrl.enterpassword("demo");     
        loginUrl.clickonloginbutton();    
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please provide the Stacktrace.

Comment: This line has capital 'L' - LoadUrl=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoadUrl.class); - instead of a lower case 'l'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `@BeforeTest` is run BEFORE `@BeforeClass` annotation. This causes your `driver` to be used BEFORE initialization.

Switch

```
@BeforeClass    
public void beforeClass()    
{    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();    
}
```

to

```
@BeforeSuite    
public void beforeClass()    
{    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();    
}
```

`@BeforeSuite` runs first, before any other annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! i refer documentation, i understand now

Comment: @kiranc Accept my answer :)